# Reference to a value storage: object, ValueType or dynamic

Tags: c#, object, dynamic, value-type

I am receiving data from third-party lib in form of this class

```
public class Value
{
    public virtual byte asByte();
    public virtual double asDouble();
    public virtual int asInt();
    public virtual long asLong();
    public virtual string asString();
}
```

After receiving I must save it in own table-like classes. Many of business-layer classess will use this tables, each working with own set of tables, so my table class must not be strongly typed. Each client of table must cast each value to it's real type (and handle casting exception of course).

Now I'm considering a number of ways to store values in table:

```
class FieldObj
{
    public object Value { get; private set; }

    // .  .  .
}


class FieldVT
{
    public ValueType Value { get; private set; }

    // .  .  .
}


class FieldDyn
{
    public dynamic Value { get; private set; }

    // .  .  .
}
```

Which variant of field should I use? I need clients to be fast while reading it.

Comment: Is keeping the `Value` class that you are supplied not an option? `public Value Value { get; private set; }`

Comment: That's third party class. I think I need to separate it from my business-logic layer.

Comment: OK you could replicate it though. Or another option could be to start your own empty "Value" class, and add methods and functionality as they become required. Problem is, we can't foresee how this will be used yet. So I would say, whatever you do, just be prepared to refactor, and for that, ensure you have good test coverage.

Comment: why not create an interface with those 5 methods and use it as type for `Value` field

Comment: @ArturUdod `Value` class is not mine. So I need to create wrapper around it, right?

Comment: @astef, y, some kind of proxy